# get specific row from mysql table with conditions

Tags: mysql

I have below mentioned table:

```
ID     Value
KA-1   A
KA-1   B
KA-1   C
KA-1   D
KA-2   A
KA-2   C
KA-2   C
KA-2   D
KA-3   C
KA-3   B
```

I want to fetch those `ID` where there is at least one value corresponding to it is `D` But the same `ID` don't have value `B`.

Required Output:

```
ID
KA-2
```

Comment: share your code that you have tried so far !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution would be:

```
select distinct id from table
   where value='D' and id not in (select distinct id from table where value='B')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY ID
HAVING SUM(VALUE='D')>=1 AND SUM(VALUE='B')=0;
```

See a working [DEMO on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a4c58/2).

Answer (score 1):

You can try with exists and not exists:

```
select id 
from table1 as a
where exists (select *
              from table1 b
              where b.value='D' and b.id=a.id)
      and not exists (select *
              from table1 c
              where c.value='B' and c.id=a.id)
```